# Fluent NHibernate Combine Date and Time field into DateTime object

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a database table (which I cannot change) which stores the date and time in separate fields but my class only has one DateTime property (Opened).

```
DateOpened 2011-05-10 00:00:00.000
TimeOpened 1899-12-30 09:53:00.000
```

In SQL I could just do

```
SELECT DateOpened + TimeOpened AS 'Opened'
```

How can I map this in Fluent NHibernate? I'm using Fluent Mapping.

I have tried

```
Map(x => x.Opened).Columns.Add(new string[] { "DateOpened", "TimeOpened" });
```

but I get the following error

```
property mapping has wrong number of columns: CBS.Tigerpaw.Data.ServiceOrder.Opened type: DateTime
```

Answer (score 2):

if IUsertype is an option

```
public class DateTimeUserType : ImmutableUserType
{
    public override object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var date = (DateTime)NHibernateUtil.DateTime.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
        var time = (DateTime)NHibernateUtil.DateTime.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
        return new DateTime(date.Year, ..., time.Hours, ...);
    }

    public override void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)(value ?? DateTime.MinValue);
        NHibernateUtil.DateTime.NullSafeSet(cmd, dt.Date, index);
        NHibernateUtil.DateTime.NullSafeSet(cmd, new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, dt.Hours, dt.Minutes, dt.Seconds), index + 1);
    }

    public override Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(DateTime); }
    }

    public override SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { SqlTypeFactory.DateTime, SqlTypeFactory.DateTime }; }
    }
}



Map(x => x.Opened)
    .Columns.Add("DateOpened", "TimeOpened")
    .CustomType<DateTimeUserType>();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define that `DateOpened + TimeOpened` by using the `.Map(...).Formula(...)` & additional property in your class which has a private setter.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider mapping the two separate columns independently and then having your class offer an additional (and un-mapped) "Opened" property that integrates their values.  Regrettably, the two mapped properties would still be visible as public properties, since Fluent NHibernate requires this so that the lambda expressions in the mapping class can get at them.

Comment: I thought of this but I am holding out for another solution. This will be my last resort.